# Number of elements in the varargs

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions, arity

I am quite confused as to how Java calculates the length of the varargs:

```
static void hello(Integer... x){

    System.out.println(x.length);
}


public static void hi(){
    hello();
}
```

This prints a 0.

When I pass :

```
static void hello(Integer... x){

    System.out.println(x.length);
}


public static void hi(){
    hello(null);
}
```

This throws a Null pointer exception.

And

```
static void hello(Integer... x){

    System.out.println(x.length);
}


public static void hi(){
    Integer[] xIntegers= new Integer[44];
    hello(xIntegers);
}
```

This prints 44.

Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: and of course it works with `hello (1,2,3,4)` as well

Answer (score 3):

Writing this:

```
static void hello(Integer... x){
```

is basically a fancy way of writing this:

```
static void hello(Integer[] x){
```

with the added bonus that you can invoke the former in this way:

```
hello(Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2));
```

instead of

```
hello(new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2)});
```

Having said that, you can still use the second form with method with varargs.

The second issue at hand is that an array, even an array of primitives, is treated as an object in Java. So if you write:

```
hello(null);
```

you are invoking `hello` with a parameter that is a `null` array of `Integer`s, and *not* `new Integer[]{null}`.

The first call passes an empty array, so the length is 0. Similarly, the third call passes an array of length 44, and you get that as the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a non `null` integer array to your `hello()` method, then as you have seen you can access the length without any problem.  You should therefore check for `null` input and equate that to an array of length zero:

```
static void hello(Integer... x) {
    int length = x == null ? 0 : x.length;
    System.out.println(length);

    if (x == null) return;

    // otherwise do something
}

public static void hi() {
    hello(null);
}
```

Note that values are just passed as an array, and you would have the same problem with the following version of `hello()`:

```
static void hello(Integer[] x) { }
```

In this case, if you also tried to read the length of a `null` input, you would get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

if the reason is that every array has length if its content has value, remember that each position of the array is a variable of the same type as its container so if you send null the array is empty where you need to validate with an if it is null print null

```
static void hello(Integer... x){
  if(x!=null)
   System.out.println(x.length);
  else
    System.out.println('is null');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a declaration of

```
static void hello(Integer... x)
```

You can call it by either passing exactly one `Integer[]` (which becomes the `x` inside the method), or passing zero or more `Integer`s (and the compiler will create an `Integer[]` out of that and that becomes the `x` inside the method).

In the case of

```
hello(null)
```

it's ambiguous whether you are trying to pass a `null` value of type `Integer[]`, or whether you are trying to pass a single `null` value of type `Integer` (both would be legal). It defaults to the former (`null` value of type `Integer[]`), and thus `x` inside the method is `null`, and not an array of a single `null` element. Trying to access `.length` on `null` causes an exception.

If you want to pass a single `null` `Integer`, you could resolve the ambiguity by explicitly casting it to `Integer`:

```
hello((Integer)null);
```

or assign it to a variable of type `Integer` first:

```
Integer x = null;
hello(x);
```

These will print a length of 1.